# How to avoid circular cache invalidation infinite-loop

Tags: php, caching

Let's assume we've got an app in this structure:

```
Client
--ClientUser
----Questionnaire
------Question
```

We are caching every one of these items. If i invalidate one of these items, it needs to be propagated to up and down. Because after adding a new question, questionnaire's questionCount will be obsolete. Also, after chaning client's name the client array in the cached ClientUser object will be obsolete.

So every invalidation code must call it's parent's and children's invalidate code too. But, after invalidating a question, it propagates up and invalidates the client too. But client invalidation code also propagates down and this goes on and on..

How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways, depending on whether loops are possible.

1. Never propagate an invalidation back to the object you got it from.
2. Have an object associated with an invalidation in progress and have it keep track of every object that's already been invalidated. Objects being invalidated must ask this object to invalidate other objects for them, and it will not invalidate an object that has already been invalidated as part of this invalidation.